# How to tag unlisted games

Tags: support, questions, tags

I looked around but wasn't able to find anything. I have questions about rules for unlisted games.

What tags should I use for games that are not listed under the existing tags? I found this [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tags/untagged/info) tag, but according to the definition, it doesn't fit the requirement.

I also didn't find any tags referring to rules and regulations.

Could you point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By 'unlisted games', do you mean you want to ask a question about a game for which no tag currently exists?

If so, the short answer is: please do ask, and don't worry about it! Another site user will come and tag it for you, if you don't have the reputation to create the new tag yourself. If you are really concerned, you can flag for moderator attention and we'll do it. See this [related discussion](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/992/50) for more.

We prefer to avoid tags like 'rules' as these are [highly generic metatags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) which could be applied to many questions, but aren't really searchable and don't add any real value. See e.g. [this discussion](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/how-should-we-tag-questions).

Comment: Beat me by 56 seconds!

Comment: @shujaa - Great, now I can reap all that awesome meta rep! Oh wait... ;)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for you question, it makes me feel justified in my answer to [this old meta question](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/992/1749)!

The accepted answer there, and probably the best solution as most new users of the site aren't a scrupulous as you, is to pick any old tag and either comment or mention at the end of the question that you need re-tagging.

RE: [rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules), we worked to eliminate it when, [after much discussion](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/818/1749), we decided it was a "meta-tag" that wasn't adding much. Most of the questions on the site are about rules, but no one can be an expert on "rules" in general, and no one has come up with a question that should exclusively get the "rules" tag, thus it has been purged.

Comment: +1. For what it's worth, I don't actually have a problem with creating a [tag:retag] tag. I just think it's hard to publicise and almost no one will use it (evidently this user was an exception, although how he would learn of its existence is still unclear to me).

Comment: @ire_and_curses I agree. Any solution I can think of will either be well-publicized and abused by lazy new users, or will be out-of-the-way and hard to find by even diligent new users like the OP here. I'm just happy to find evidence careful new users.

Comment: I've just come across this problem myself, and duly scoured through all the existing tags.  I ended up picking an arbitrary one and leaving a comment/apology in the question.  I would certainly have found it useful for there to have been something explicit like `no-current-tag-fits-please-retag`.  I feel that just `retag` is liable to be overlooked by anyone scanning the list, whereas a long one is big and clunky enough to be spotted, and quickly changed on a question.