# Could someone add a "Mississippi Queen" tag please?

Tags: support

I've a question relating to this game but no way to tag it.  Thanks.

(Is this the right way to make such a request?)

Answer (score 2):

This is not the right way to get new tags.

The way to get new tags is to simply ask the question, providing bogus tags or no tag if there is not one that matches your question.

Optionally - Flag the question as needing mod attention saying that there was no tag, or add a comment/note at the end of your question.

Higher rep users will see the new question, look at it, and fix/create the tags for you.

[How to tag unlisted games](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/how-to-tag-unlisted-games?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks.  A couple of comments. **1** I'd already read the post you linked to, where the answer is *"the short answer is: please do ask"* - so I asked :-)  **2**. It would be helpful to either add this guidance to the question page, or maybe have a tag that means "help-can't-find-suitable-tag' or some such.

Comment: @Cheeseminer 1. I think by 'Please do ask' means, just ask the question, not ask for the tag. 2. I agree it would be helpful to have it on th question page or FAQ. I think the untagged tag filled this role previously, but it was decided that we would rather not have it as these types of problems do not come up that often.